# admob banner position / notification bar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I'm working on putting ads in my android game project with libgdx.  I saw this code on the web  and it worked for me.  The problem is it shows the notification bar on the top and the position of the ad is on bottom left part of the screen which obscures the view of the character.  The game is on landscape position and I want to put the ad on bottom center part.  How can I take off the notification bar and put the ad on a correct position. I'm just new in java and I don't understand this code. Thank you.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //gameViewParams.bottomMargin = 150;
    requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    View gameView = initializeForView(new ZBGame(), cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView, gameViewParams);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("YOUR ADMOB AD ID");
    //adView.setAdUnitId("app-id");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: I already figure it out. I used this code. [link](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't done this yet, but I would assume you would add another rule to adParams to center the view.

For example:

```
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```